# How to hide leading stars in windowless emacs org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, terminal-emacs

I've been working hard to get emacs and org-mode working inside of my tmux workflow. And i've got a pretty decent setup. :)

I installed org-bullets to get utf8 bullets, it worked. But even if I set into my emacs init file that I want the clean view it show the previous stars for every item. Also tried with the in-file solution but nothing.

Here is specifically what I tried

on my init:

```
;; Hide leading stars
(setq org-startup-indented t
      org-hide-leading-stars t)
```

On my org file:

```
#+STARTUP: indent
```

It works perfectly on the windowed environment, buy inside my terminal
stars didn't disappear

Answer (score 8):

The variable `org-hide-leading-stars` just uses the face `org-hide` behind the scenes.

Pressing <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> (to get help on a variable) and then typing `org-hide-leading-stars`<kbd>Enter</kbd> will show you what you need to do.

The documentation for the variable says

> Non-nil means hide the first N-1 stars in a headline. This works by
>   using the face `org-hide` for these stars.  This face is white for a
>   light background, and black for a dark background.  **You may have to
>   customize the face `org-hide` to make this work.**

Emphasis mine.

You can customize the face by typing
<kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-face`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`org-hide`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Set the foreground color of the face to the colour of your background in tmux.

Comment: This should be the beginning of the answer. Thank you so much. Though, even after customizing the org-hide face, it doesn't work in -nw mode, just in the gui. :(

Comment: Some follow up information for Mac+iTerm users: if you can still see the stars, even after following the advice of Gambo, then: 1. open your iterm preferences
2. navigate to the colour preferences for your preferred profile
3. drag the minimum contrast slider all the way to the left